# "basic_string::_M_construct null not valid" while using cpprest library

Tags: c++, cpprest-sdk

I'm starting working with C++ and it's cpprestsdk. I've searched a lot and also tried to copy valid examples from the internet but nothing works. Can anyone help me to deal with this error? This code compiles, but it's throwing the exception "basic_string::_M_construct null not valid" at `auto response = client.request(request).get();`

```cpp
#include <cpprest/filestream.h>
#include <cpprest/http_client.h>
#include <cpprest/uri.h>
#include <cpprest/json.h>


using namespace utility;
using namespace web;
using namespace web::http;
using namespace web::http::client;
using namespace concurrency::streams;

...

try {
        auto client = client::http_client{ U("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/") };
        auto request = http_request{ methods::POST };
        request.set_request_uri(U("/posts"));

        // Exception is thrown here. If i'll comment everything under this line, code works.
        auto response = client.request(request).get(); 

        logprintf("Logged: %d", response.status_code());
    }
    catch (std::exception& e) {
        logprintf("ERROR %s", e.what());
    }
```

`logprintf` is just a wrapper for `printf`. It's working fine.

Comment: What's with the wide string literals? I suspect that may have something to do with it. What happens if you change `U"whatever"` with `u8"whatever"`?

Comment: Probably the core problem isn't in code. I hope that's a limitations of SAMP (platform where I'm using this script). So now I've figured it out and moved this code part into other location and everything works fine.